# Upload files using multer

Tags: multer

hello when i send an image to my express app using multer it dosen't save it in the destination 
this is what i've done
[express code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJAi.png)

and this is a screen shot of postman request
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwQk.png)
[destination folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRQ6c.png)

Comment: whats the question here ? Whats wrong ?

Comment: i don't know what i've done wrong could you help ?  i want to store an image in the server using multer in the ../images folder the thing is multer is not storing it in the destination